# Can’t play sound on vlc when running Python script from bash shell script?

Tags: python, linux, bash, audio, vlc

I have a Python script that repeatedly plays a sound using the cvlc command.  The Python script works fine when run through the command line or from a bash shell script through the command line but when the bash shell script is run automatically at startup, it runs without any sound.  I am using the os.system call to run the cvlc command however, I noticed that it is adding “sh -c” to the beginning of the command.  I believe this is causing an issue as vlc as won’t play any sound with this command.  Does anyone know how to prevent the “sh -c” from being added to the beginning of the command? Below is my code for the Python script and the bash shell script that runs automatically on startup.

Python script:

```
import is
import time
import multiprocessing

def make_sound():
    os.system(‘cvlc air_horn.wav’)

while True:
    process = multiprocessing.Process(target=make_sound, name=“Make Sound”)
    process.start()
    time.sleep(3)
    process.terminate()
    process.join()
```

Bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd path/to/Python/script
sleep 10
python3 make_sound.py
```

Comment: maybe don't use `os.system()` but one of the functions in module `subprocess` - and then you can run program without using shell.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain in more detail what you mean with "*when the bash shell script is run automatically at startup*". How exactly do you make the script run at startup?

Comment: I added the bash shell script to the rc.local file which then runs it every time the system is powered on.

Comment: **Please add all requested information or clarification to the question.** In `rc.local` the script will have a different environment and might run as a different user. Show the exact command you added to the rc file. Do you see that your Python program is running when you start the script from the rc file? I suggest to redirect the script's `stdout` + `stderr` to a file in `rc.local` and check the file for error messages, e.g. `/path/to/your/bash_script >> /tmp/bash_script.log 2>&1 &` or similar. If your script shall be run by `bash` you should add `#!/bin/bash` or similar as the first line.

Comment: The Python script is running from the root user and I did have #!/bin/bash at the beginning of the bash shell script.

Comment: The command I added to rc.local is path/to/bash/script/bash_script.sh right before exit 0

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add requested information, don't use comments for this purpose. Please answer all questions and follow all suggestions. Is the command `path/to/bash/script/bash_script.sh` or `/path/to/bash/script/bash_script.sh`? Change it to `/path/to/bash/script/bash_script.sh >> /tmp/bash_script.log 2>&1 &` and restart your system. What output do you get in the log file?

Comment: Does `root` have any idea as to where `air_horn.wav` is on the disc? Adding the path might help.